# Fail to put logo in navigation bar website Hugo Academic theme

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, hugo

I am new to his forum, so my apologies if I breach any common rules (please instruct where I go wrong)

I have built a webpage for a new project, using templates (Rmd) in RStudio. All is well, but I fail to manage to get a logo in the navigation bar (next to the menu items). I have looked extensively on the Hugo pages itself, and some code on GitHub repositories. All without any luck. 
The only code that I could find is repeated below. But is does not get me anywhere.

```
in the config/_default/params.toml

main_menu = {align = "c", show_logo = true}
logo = "x.png"

with he logo in the appropriate folder (static/im)
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from the *navbar.html* layout file, the image file must be named *logo.png* (or *logo.svg*) and must be placed in the *assets\images* directory of your hugo project.

It may be necessary to relauch the hugo server to see the changes.